# Scale a number by given range

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I have a UI slider that returns a value in the range of 0 - 1 based on it's position, e.g.:

```
    0
    0.008333333333333333
    0.041666666666666664
    0.08333333333333333
    0.10833333333333334
    0.125
    0.13333333333333333
    0.14166666666666666
    0.16666666666666666
    0.175
    0.19166666666666668
    0.2
    0.21666666666666667
    0.24166666666666667
    0.2833333333333333
    0.31666666666666665
    0.36666666666666664
    0.4083333333333333
    0.425
    0.48333333333333334
    0.55
    0.6166666666666667
    0.7
    0.775
    0.825
    0.8833333333333333
    0.9333333333333333
    0.9833333333333333
    1
```

I'm controlling a zoom level with the slider, which has a minimum value of 1 and a maximum value of 6.

How can I scale the number to sync with the range of zoom values?

Comment: Multiply the value by 6 ?

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ, no, because 0 * 6 = 0, not 1

Comment: Thanks, i know that, it was a bit ironic..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just calculate

```
function f(x)  {          // [0 ... 1]
    return 5 * x + 1;     // [1 ... 6]
}
```

The other way round

```
function f(y)  {          // [1 ... 6]
    return (y - 1) / 5;   // [0 ... 1]
}
```

Comment: may be function `f(x, min, max)  {
    return (max-1) * x + min;
}`

Comment: Thanks @NinaScholz ;)